# Merge multiple directories into one, named according to the common directory prefix

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, directory

I made a batch file to rename directories to the string preceding **`-`**, but now there is a problem:

Let's say, for example, I had these folders:

> Naruto - 480p
>   Naruto - 720p
>   Naruto - 1080p

I want to have only one directory, named `Naruto`, which contains the content of those three directories.

I use this batch file:

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims=-" %%a in ('dir /b "*-*.*"') do ren "%%a-%%b" "%%a%%~xb"
```

…but even with the batch file the resultant directories seem to be:

> Naruto
>   Naruto - 720p
>   Naruto - 1080p

How can I merge the three directories into one which will be named `Naruto`?

Comment: You cannot rename three directories in one location to the same name, _for the same reason you cannot have three files in one directory with the same name and extension!_ You need to `ren`ame, `move` files and `r`emove `d`irectories, or `m`ake `d`irectory, `move` files and `r`emove `d`irectories.

Comment: There is no **`.`** character in your directory names either!

Comment: You should also use the `/AD` option so that the `DIR` command only lists folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well, you want to merge these three folders. This is not possible in batchfile language, so you need to move content of the two folders into one, remove them and rename the remaining folder. This is a way you can do it:

```bat
@echo off
:: Batch script that merges 3 folders into one!
:: We assume that these 3 folders are located in C:\ .

for /R C:\Naruto-480p %%a IN (*.*) do move "%%a" C:\Naruto-1080p
for /R C:\Naruto-720p %%b IN (*.*) do move "%%b" C:\Naruto-1080p
rd Naruto-480p Naruto-720p
rename Naruto-1080p Naruto
```

Now let's break out the batch file program:

Lines starting with `::` are comments, they are ignored. In fact, they are invalid labels.

`for /R C:\Naruto-480p %%a IN (*.*) do @move "%%a" C:\Naruto-1080p` and `for /R C:\Naruto-720p %%b IN (*.*) do @move "%%b" C:\Naruto-1080p`. `for` is a loop as you already know. The `/R` option tells the loop to run through all the subfolders of the folder specified in the start (C:\Naturo-480p and C:\Naruto-720p respectively). `IN (*.*)` means to process ALL files found and, finally, move each file.

`rd Naruto-480p Naruto-720p` removes folders `Naruto-480p` and `Naruto-720p`.

`rename Naruto-1080p Naruto` renames the folder.

I hope that this helps you exit your trouble :-).